# need help in eliminating race condition in my code

Tags: tcl, expect

My code is running infinitely without coming out of loop.
I am calling expect script from shell script, that is working fine,
the problem here is script is not coming out of timout {} loop.
can someone help me in this regard.

```
    spawn ssh ${USER}@${MACHINE}
    set timeout 10
    expect "Password: "
    send -s "${PASS}\r"

    expect $prompt
    send "cmd\r"

    expect $prompt
    send "cmd1\r"

    expect $prompt
    send "cmd2\r"

    expect $prompt
    send "cmd3\r"

    expect $prompt
    send "cmdn\r"
    #cmdn --> is about running script which takes around 4 hours

    expect {
         timeout { puts "Running ....."  #<--- script is nout coming out of loop its running infinitely
         exp_continue   }
         eof {puts "EOF occured"; exit 1}
         "\$.*>" { puts "Finished.." ; exit 0}


    }
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that your real pattern, `"\$.*>"`, is being matched *literally* and not as a regular expression. You need to pass the `-re` flag for that pattern to be matched as a RE, like this (I've used more lines than `;` chars as I think it is clearer that way, but YMMV there):

```
expect {
    timeout {
        puts "Running ....."
        exp_continue
    }
    eof {
        puts "EOF occured"
        exit 1
    }
    -re {\$.*>} {
        puts "Finished.."
        exit 0
    }
}
```

It's also a ***really good idea*** to put regular expressions in `{`braces`}` if you can, so backslash sequences (and other Tcl metacharacters) inside don't get substituted. You don't have to… but 99.99% of all cases are better that way.

Comment: Thanks Donal for your help. with changes as you suggested i tried with changes still i see the same output.    the script is hung inside timeout and continuosly printing Runiing....                                                                                             Running .....
Running .....
Running .....
Running .....
Running .....
Running .....
Running .....
Running .....
Running .....
Running .....